# How to rotate a view 180 degrees using a rotation animation

Tags: android, android-view, android-transitions

I want to turn a view upside down, using `TransitionManager` and `ChangeTransform` to animate the rotation.
If rotating the view 90 degrees, the rotation works fine.
However, if rotating the view 180 degrees, the `ChangeTransform` decides to instead fade/shrink/flip the view vertically, i.e., apply a translation instead.

Is there any way using `ChangeTransform` to get arbitrarily rotated views to actually always animate using *rotation* instead of `ChangeTransform` itself deciding for me what to use based on some internal priorities that decides when to choose translation vs rotation?

```
<changeTransform android:duration="500" android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_cubic">
    <targets>
        <target android:targetId="@id/icon" />
    </targets>
</changeTransform>

[...]

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(viewRoot, rotateTransition); 
icon.setRotation(180.0f)
```

Comment: From what I can tell, internally the transformation is represented by a matrix, so after setting rotation there is no difference internally between 180 degree rotation and flip. As a workaround you can perhaps animate to 179.99f and then adjust to 180.0f manually after rotation is complete?